# Conditional text on Kendo UI Button using a different cells value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a button that when clicked I'm pushing some of the data rows value into an array.  I swap the text based on its selected/unselected state.  This works great, but if the user pages through the datagrid or filters it, the selected value remains but the button text changs back to its "add" state.  Here is my code for the button:

```
    command: [
                { 
                   name: "Select", template:  "<a href='\\\#' class='k-button k-button-icontext btn-destroy k-grid-Select'>#= this.Selected === true ? 'Remove' : 'Add' #</a>",
click: function (e) {
                     var curBtn = $(e.target);
                     var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
                     var data = this.dataItem(tr);
                     console.log(data);
                     var selected = data.Selected;

                     if (selected == false || selected == undefined) {
                         data.Selected = true;
                         curBtn.html('remove');
                     }
                     else { 
                         data.Selected = false;
                         curBtn.html('add');
                     }
                     console.log(curBtn);
                     data.refresh();
             }

         }],
```

I tried this for the template but kept getting an invalid template error.  I believe the cause of this is that I don't directly have access to items outside of the data cell?

```
 template:  "<a href='\\\#' class='k-button k-button-icontext btn-destroy k-grid-Select'>#= Selected == true ? Remove : Add #</a>"
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as usual!!  Thanks and happy coding!

EDIT:

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rKBZq/27/

This is pretty representative of what I'm trying to do.  The data is local just as it is in this demo.  So basically, based on the row's selected property I want to change the text of the button to either "ADD" or "REMOVE" and update the row and data appropriately via the click action...

Somethings I observed is when console.log(data) the selected value is infact updated... however, the grid cell is now.  that is fine because i usually hide it anyway... so is it possible that the this.Selected i have slugged in to the template is pulling from the table row instead of the backing data?  -- EDIT:  adding this.refresh() updates the table as well but the button does not rerender when doing so...  I updated the command button to reflect it too, and it does save while paging or filtering... so this comes down to how come the button does not refresh / rerender when calling refresh when the data does?

Another observation is obviously I shouldn't HAVE to do curBtn.html('Add') if this works... I'm hoping to swap the state of the button accordingly as the data changes...

Comment: Strike that, not invalid template error, it says Selected is not defined which it is because the first version works but obviously only checks state of data cell when binding...

Comment: Would be possible post the code in JSFiddle/JSBin for having the full picture of it?

Comment: Ya I'll do that now... do you know of any handy external resources to the kendo web ui stuff?

Comment: Ok i added a fiddle.  thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but as far as I know it is not possible doing what you want using `command`. I cannot find in Kendo UI Grid documentation references to `template` in a command and when added a trace to see when the template is expanded I see that it is only executed when the Grid is loaded the first time.

You can easily verify that if you set some of the initial `Selected` state to `true` the `button` is actually not initialized correctly.

**BUT** this doesn't mean that you cannot do something similar (get the same result).

What I propose is instead of defining it as a `command`, define it as a `field` and then use your `template`.

Doing this you still have some problems to solve:

1. There is not `click` event for a field so you should add some code after the grid initialization for doing this.
2. Avoid that when clicked, the field `Selected` enters in edition mode. If you try this using `editable: false` then you cannot change the value of `Selected` so what I do is a little trick consisting of defining `field` as empty and then define the `title` to what we want.
3. If you update a field in a `DataSource` using `data.Selected = true`, you are not actually setting it in the model and so when paging you loose it. So you should use `set` for updating the value.

Doing this your code would be:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: suppds,
    filterable: true,
    sortable  : true,
    height    : "600px",
    pageable  : {
        input  : true,
        numeric: false
    },
    save      : function () {
        this.refresh();
    },
    editable  : true,
    columns   : [
        {
            field : "",
            title : "Selected",
            template: "<a href='\\\#' class='k-button k-button-icontext btn-destroy k-grid-Select'>#= data.Selected == true ? 'Remove' : 'Add' #</a>",
            width  : "100px"
        },
        { field: "OrderDate", title: "Date", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" },
        {
            field     : "Title", title: "Title",
            filterable: {
                extra    : false,
                operators: {
                    string: {
                        contains: "Contains"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { field: "Records", title: "Records" },
        { field: "Selected"  }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");

$(grid.tbody).on("click", ".k-grid-Select", function (e) {
    var curBtn = $(e.target);
    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
    var data = grid.dataItem(tr);
    var selected = data.Selected;
    console.log(curBtn);
    console.log(data);
    if (selected == false || selected == undefined) {
        data.set("Selected", true);
        curBtn.text('Remove');
    }
    else {
        data.set("Selected", false);
        curBtn.text('Add');
    }
});
```

and the modified JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rKBZq/39/

Comment: Excellent!  This will do the job, This would be cool feature -- I'm used to using knockout w/ observables so much I almost expect the behavior these days :P... Thanks again for your assistance!